# How to deserialize json data coming from web api directly

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to deserialize JSON data coming from Web Api directly .But it is throwinn error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TestMvc.Controllers.HomeController+TestJson]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.

My code:

```
  public class TestJson
    {
        public string thing1
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string thing2
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

  using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            var json = wc.DownloadString("http://localhost:43560/api/carvalues");

           List <TestJson> exam = new List<TestJson>();

           exam = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TestJson>>(json);

        }
```

**Sample of json data**

```
{"thing1":"first thing","thing2":"second thing"}
```

My objective is how can I deserialize the data coming from WebAPI directly. I am using Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case use it without list

```
var exam = new TestJson();    
exam = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestJson>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

Example json data indicates it is just one object coming back in the response where you are expecting array/list of the objects.

Modify the webapi to return list instead of single object and it should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data needs to be on array, something like this

```
"data": [{
    "thing1": "first thing",
    "thing2": "second thing"
}, {
    "thing1": "first thing",
    "thing2": "second thing"
}, {
    "thing1": "first thing",
    "thing2": "second thing"
}]
```

Or use plain class i.e. particular to this case

```
exam = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestJson>(json);
```